# calling Completable action after dispose() on Flowable

Tags: rx-java2

I have an asynchronous action modeled as `Completable`:

```
Completable onCancel = onCancel();
```

I have a `Flowable`:

```
Flowable<Integer> f = flowable();
```

I want to trigger the `onCancel` action when a subscription to the flowable is disposed:

```
f.subscribe().dispose();
```

The only way I can think of doing this is by subscribing to the `onCancel` from within `doOnCancel` like so:

```
f.doOnCancel(() -> onCancel.blockingAwait())
```

Is this the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: If you are using `blockingAwait()` then you are probably doing something wrong. There is no point in doing things reactively (`Completable`) and then using blocking functions (`blockingAwait()`) - they are last resort. But without knowing your context is hard to give definitive answer. Can you please describe your use case?

Comment: yeah, well, imagine that you want to send an info to some database that a stream has been canceled, and you have it modeled with `Completable`. I agree that subscribing inside a flow to another flow looks strange, I guess that's why I am asking this question, I just can't see any other way.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with subscribing inside a flow to another flow. But alternatively, you could think if you can represent **event that causes cancellation of your subscription** as `Observable` and then subscribe to this event. In that case you don't have to react to cancellation, but just to this event directly. Of course if it can be done is dependent on your context.

What is a big smell in your example is doing `blockingAwait()` which forces asynchronous task to be done synchronously - there is no point in using RxJava then.

You can simply subscribe to your `Completable`:

```java
doOnCancel(() -> completable.subscribe(
        () -> System.out.println("Completed!"),
        e -> System.out.println("Completed with error: " + e)
))
```

Or even `doOnCancel(completable::subscribe)` - not recommended, because then you lose all info about completion and errors.